# five-fold cross-validation with the use of linear regression

Tags: r

I would like to perform a five-fold cross validation for a regression model of degree 1

```
lm(y ~ poly(x, degree=1), data).
```

I generated 100 observations with the following code

```
set.seed(1)
GenData <- function(n){
  x <- seq(-2,2,length.out=n)
  y <- -4 - 3*x + 1.5*x^2 + 2*x^3 + rnorm(n,0,0.5)
  return(cbind(x,y))
}
GenData(100)
D<-GenData(100)
```

and my code for this goal is

```
ind<-sample(1:100)
re<-NULL
k<-20
teams<- 5
t<-NULL
for (i in 1:teams) {
  te<- ind[ ((i-1)*k+1):(i*k)]
  train <- D[-te,1:2]
  test <-   D[te,1:2]
  cl <- D[-te,2]
  lm1 <- lm(cl ~train[,1] , data=train)
  pred <- predict(lm1,test)
  t<- c(t,   sum(D[te,2] == pred)    /dim(test)[1])
}
re<-c(re,mean(t))
```

where I split my data into training and test.With the training data I run a regression with purpose to make a prediction and comperate it with my test data.But I have the following error

> ```
> "Error in predict(mult, test)$class : 
>  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> In addition: Warning message:
> 'newdata' had 20 rows but variables found have 80 rows "
> ```

So I understand that I have to change something on the line

```
    pred<-predict(lm1,test)
```

but I dont know what .
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`lm` requires a data frame as input data. Also trying to validate the model by just verifying if the result matches the expected value will not work. You are simulating the irreducible error using normal error.

Here is the updated code:

```
ind<-sample(1:100)
re<-NULL
k<-20
teams<- 5
t<-NULL

for (i in 1:teams) {
   te<- ind[ ((i-1)*k+1):(i*k)]
   train <- data.frame(D[-te,1:2])
   test <-   data.frame(D[te,1:2])
   lm1 <- lm(y~x , data=train)
   pred <- predict(lm1,test)
   t<- c(t,   sum(abs(D[te,2] - pred))    /dim(test)[1])
}

re<-c(re,mean(t))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `lm()` function, your `y` variable is `cl`, a vector not included in the `data =` argument:

```
cl <- D[-te,2]
lm1 <- lm(cl ~train[,1] , data=train)
```

No need to include the `cl` at all. Rather, simply specify `x` and `y` by their names in the dataset `train`, in this case the names are x and y:

```
names(train)
[1] "x" "y"
```

So your for loop would then look like:

```
for (i in 1:teams) {
  te<- ind[ ((i-1)*k+1):(i*k)]
  train <- D[-te,1:2]
  test <-   D[te,1:2]
  lm1 <- lm(y ~x , data=train)
  pred <- predict(lm1,test)
  t[i]<- sum(D[te,2] == pred)/dim(test)[1]
}
```

Also, note that I have added the `for` loop index `i` so that values can be added to the object. Lastly, I had to make the `D` object a dataframe in order for the code to work:

```
D<-as.data.frame(GenData(100))
```

Your `re` object ends up being `0` because your model does not predict any numbers correctly. I would suggest using RMSE as a performance measure for continuous data.